# Weird insertion times into MongoDB

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to save lots of sensor measurements and I'm doing some benchmarks on MongoDB.

**The data:**
This is the "schema" I'm using:

```
public class BetterConsolidatedTag
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The base time to which the offset values relate.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime BaseTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the data series
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Values of the series in this time frame. The values are saved as offsets in milliseconds from the BaseTime.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonElement]
    private SortedDictionary<int, object> OffsetValues { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that instead of saving each measurement by itself I consolidate all the measurements for a specific sensor over an hour. So each document represents all the measurements for a specific sensor over an hour which starts on `BaseTime`.
There are two indexes defined: BaseTime_1_Name_1 and Name_1_BaseTime_1.

**The database**
MongoDB is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard with the following hardware:

- Processor:   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5675  @ 3.07GHz, 3059 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
- RAM: 96GB
- Disk: 300GB local disk with RAID 1 (IBM ServeRAID M5015)
- Network: Intel® 82575EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller

**The benchmark**
For simplicity, my simulation generates data at a constant rate - I generate data which represents an hour for all the different sensors and save it to the database. I log the time it takes to save this one-hour data (which as mentioned above, contains the same number of samples each time).
The data generation was on my desktop (Windows 7 Enterprise, i7, 8GB RAM, SSD) which sent the data to the MongoDB server over the network using the official MongoDB C# driver. I didn't do anything special with the desktop during the test - mainly internet browsing and plotting the measurements in Excel from time to time. No one but me was connected to the remote server during this time and no one but my benchmark was connected to the MongoDB during the benchmarking.

**The results**
This is a graph depicting insert time (in ms) as a function of the total number of samples in the database (the total size of the DB is about 200GB, saved across 101 files):
[image: Sensor data insertion time]

And with some zoom:
[image: Sensor data insertion time zoomed to lower values]
I'm having trouble understanding these results. I expected the insertion time to grow slightly over time - there are two indexes and as number of documents increases it's to be expected that maintaining these indexes takes longer. Also, I expected that once data doesn't fit into physical memory anymore and paging begins to occur more frequently the insertion times should become much higher, but the graph doesn't look like there's a single point in time when things get worse.
And what I *really* don't understand is why this graph looks as if it's made up of three different graphs - 
 - One which grows very slowly, and holds almost all the data points (this is what I expected all the results to look like)
 - One which grows faster and holds less points (maybe these are the times when paging occurs? But it's expect a "jump" in the graph at the point where physical memory got filled up)
- One which grows insanely and holds about 40 data points. These data points seem to occur at a constant rate of about every 15 minutes. I thought perhaps these are the times MongoDB creates a new file but the data is saved across 101 files while there are only about 40 of these weird measurements.

Do these results make any sense? If not, what might be the problem? Should I look for mysterious background jobs on the server? A hardware problem?

**EDIT**: It doesn't make sense that the high points correspond to file creation because it shouldn't take more time to create files as data gets larger. Maybe there's some sort of compaction MongoDB is doing in the background? Something along the lines of most of the time small compactions (the second "graph" and sometimes full compactions (the third and highest "graph"). It would make sense that compaction takes longer as data grows larger. Or maybe garbage collection, which can also be represented by such behavior, I guess?

**EDIT 2**: Well, MongoDB is written in C++ so I guess GC is out of the question. So right now background compaction is my best guess.

Comment: Files are preallocated in MongoDB. When the first data is written to a preallocated file, the next one is preallocated. And there is no such thing as background compaction. Running MongoDB on a Windows server, however, is a bit comparable of making an Olympic level sprinter running on high heels: The filesystems are at least 25% slower than ext4 and XFS and the OS tries to save memory.

Comment: But let's say I'm OK with it being slower. Shouldn't it be uniformly slower? It's not like I have a general problem with the performance. My problem is that I don't understand the phenomenon with the sudden peaks in insert and the peaks just keep getting higher and higher.

Comment: That depends on the size and the speed of the bursts, IOPs available, wether file access needs to be made (which is a rather complicated topic) the size of your journal and whatnot. From what I can see, I would say the percentage of inserts taking longer is what I would expect of a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: I generate the simulation data in a tight loop - 360000 samples which represent data for an hour, which I then consolidate by the sensor name and then I save all the documents together using `InsertBatch`. The graphs represent only the time this `InsertBatch` takes. The time to generate the data is always 200-300ms without any outliers.

Answer (score 2):

By default MongoDB performs fsync once in a minute, so once in a minute you will have much slower insert - that's the point when data is actually saved to the disk, the rest of the time it's saved only in memory. Set it to sync data every second (or on every write if possible) and the graph will look different.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - the amount of data I generate every minute is constant. Why does it take more and more time to save it? Do you think it's because I generate data quicker than MongoDB is able to write it and it keeps accumulating unsaved data?

Comment: Also, the performance hazards happen once every 15 minutes and not once a minute...

Comment: OK, so I looked at the data again, and what I described above as the medium graph is almost explained by your answer. Indeed the samples on this graph appear in 1-minute intervals. However, why is this graph growing and not constant?

Comment: @Dina Well, indexes are B-Trees. If you insert random data, then the index should be reordered, so not only it have to write the new entries but the older ones (e.g. the index is being rewritten). Growing index size -> more data to write.

Comment: Yes, of course, that's why the lowest graph keeps growing and that's totally fine by me. But each minute we write the data into the disk. I assume it's almost the same amount of data (because my simulation is almost uniform) so the time to write the data to the disk should be constant. The index should be updated as well. Does it reorder the *entire* index? In that case indeed it makes sense that it takes more time.

Comment: Now that I think about it, since I also have a Name-Time index and not just a Time-Name index indeed it makes sense that some major reorganization is to be done. I wonder if the graphs were the same if I didn't have the Name-Time index.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about the highest part of the graph? We now have an idea that it might be the antivirus. I asked IT to exclude the data folder from the antivirus scanning and will repeat the experiment after.